# jQuery.Deferred exception: chart.axisX is undefined

Tags: jquery, charts, canvasjs

All i need is the maximum and minimum point in the X-axis of this canvasJs chart.
This code is from : https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/zxrkh502/
Code used in this for that is :

```
var axisXMin = chart.axisX[0].get("minimum");

var axisXMax = chart.axisX[0].get("maximum");
```

But it always return this error

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: chart.axisX is undefined
```

When i console : chart.axisX[0].get("minimum") in js fiddle , it returns the exact required thing, but doesnot do so when i copy it in my project.

PS : Line chart is working properly though, i just cant get the points from the code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkQhE.png)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkQhE.png) that you have shared, I guess you might be using older version of CanvasJS where [getters & setters](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/methods/) were not supported.
[image: CanvasJS Line Chart]
Getting minimum / maximum of the axis were introduced in [v1.9.6](https://canvasjs.com/blog/12/22/canvasjs-charts-1-9-6-beta-methods-properties/) & you need to have version greater than v1.9.6 to use those features. Incase of [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/zxrkh502/), it's working as it uses latest version of CanvasJS from canvasjs.com.

I suggest you to **use latest version of the library** & try accessing the properties.

```
var axisXMin = chart.axisX[0].get("minimum");
var axisXMax = chart.axisX[0].get("maximum");
```

If you are still facing issue, create JSFiddle reproducing the same / share the sample project so that others can understand the use-case properly & guide you accordingly.